# Lazyloading with background url

Tags: jquery, background-image, lazy-loading

I want to use lazyloading (lazysizes). Unfortunately it's not lazyloading when using

```
<a class="lazyload" href="bigimage.jpg" style="background-image: url('smallimage,jpg');"></a>
```

Is there a way to use lazyloading with this style: background-image url method?

Comment: If you got inline css, it's going to load right away. The way I lazyload bg images is: I have a class `has-bg` on the element which has a bg and on scroll when the element is in view, I add another class `bg-loaded` to the element and in the css I have `#whatever.bg-loaded` which has the background image css rule. I do this for all different sizes of the browser that we need to support. I guess you could alternatively put the inline css in data attribute then apply it with js

Comment: But if I have 100 images, with this method, I'd have to add 100 seperate classes?

Comment: Yes if you use that method, you would need to add that many classes. So it might be best for you to put the bg style in a `data-` attribute then using js to add the inline style when you want to load the image. The first method is good if you are starting from new, adding the classes won't seem like a chore, but if you got the pages already then it might seem like a pain. Honestly it's not that bad